# how do i get a list of all tags used in a particular flickr set

Tags: set, tags, photo, flickr

with the flickr API i want to find out all tags used in one particular set of photos.

i know it's easy to find out all my tags (via `flickr.tags.getListUserPopular`), but i don't know an easy way to limit the tags to the ones used in a particular set. checking every tag against teh photos in the set is too very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a 1 step answer to this but you can get this using the existing APIs.  Start with [flickr.photosets.getList](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getList.html) and [flickr.photosets.getInfo](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getInfo.html) APIs to get the list of photos (Photo IDs) in the set you want then use [flickr.tags.getListPhoto](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.tags.getListPhoto.html) to get the tags for each of the photos.  Then create your tag histogram.  These should be all available from any of the language interfaces to flickr.